# data-toggle="tab" and data-toggle ="collapse" is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to display the content of the selected side navigation item, but somehow my data-toggle ="tab" is not working. I have searched it on several forums, made changes accordingly but still could not get it to work. As was suggested, I included the jquery link before the bootstrap link and I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com).

script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"

The part of the code is as follows:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="wrapper">
<nav id="sidebar">
<div class="sidebar-header">

<li><a href="#eventSubmenu" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle ="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Events<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="eventSubmenu">
         <li ><a href="#link1"  role= "tab" data-toggle="tab"> Link1 </a></li>
         <li ><a href="#link2" role= "tab" data-toggle ="tab"> Link2 </a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
```

[As you can see in the image the data-toggle does not change its color, in short it is not considered as a keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLNT.png)

Comment: Where is your jquery code?  You just linked the script to the library and not your actual code.  Can we see that?

Comment: Hello @AttemptedMastery I have added the jquery code which I have written for the collapse function. Could you please help me find the flaw?